# Neo4j 2.3.0 - where I can find the graphaware-server-community-al and graphaware-uuid for this 2.3.0 version

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

The recent ones I found are for version 2.2.6
Need those for 2.3.0
Currently I am using:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 neo4j adm 13171409 Sep 24 20:46 graphaware-server-community-all-2.2.5.34.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 neo4j adm    13710 Sep 24 21:45 graphaware-uuid-2.2.5.34.7.jar
```

Where I can find them?

Comment: Hi @LDB, the modules have been updated to 2.3 and are available on our products page : http://graphaware.com/products/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes always 2 or 3 days to update the plugins and ensure no bugs are introduced.

Also as most of the team is flying out San Francisco to Europe / Asia this might delay the release.

I propose to open an issue on the Github so we can be notified once the release is done.